# A test of the difference between two r-squared?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, r-squared, delta-method

According to [Olkin and Finn (1995)](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/0033-2909.118.1.155) and [Alf and Graf (1999)](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/1082-989X.4.1.70), the variance of the difference in r-squared is
$$
var(r_1^2 - r_2^2) = a \phi a^\mathsf{T},
$$
where $a = \begin{bmatrix}2 r_{1} & -2 r_{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\phi = \begin{bmatrix} var_1 & cov_{12} \\ cov_{12} & var_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Further,
$$
var_1 = \frac{(1 - r_1^2)^2}{n_1}, \\ var_2 = \frac{(1 - r_2^2)^2}{n_2}, \\ \text{and} \quad cov_{12} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} (2 r_{12} - r_1 r_2) (1 - r_1^2 - r_2^2 - r_{12}^2) + r_{12}^3}{\sqrt{n_1 n_2}}.
$$
Questions:

1. I have one sample of $y$ and $x$ and run the regression $y = a + b x + e$, which yields an r-squared $r^2$.

However, the $x$ can be measured in two ways (methods), 1 and 2. Can the 'Olkin formula' be used to test the significance of the difference between $r_1^2$ and $r_2^2$ in this case.

2. If yes, how to obtain the $r_{12}$?

If the measurement x1 does not influence the measurement $x_2$, $r_1 - r_{12} r_2 = 0$ and $r_{12} = r_1/r_2$. This implies that $1 \geq r_{12} \geq min(r_1/r_2, r_2/r_1)$? A conservative test could be to use the lower limit as a proxy for $r_{12}$?

3. Python:

from scipy.stats import norm

import numpy as np

def calculate_variance_of_difference(r_yx1, r_yx2, n_1, n_2, r_x1x2 = None):

```
"""
Calculate the variance of the difference between two r-squared, using matrix operations 
and ensuring the variance-covariance matrix is positive semi-definite. The number of 
observations n should be 'large' (n > 60).

Parameters:
    
r_yx1 (float): The correlation coefficient for the first measurement of x, denoted x1, with
the dependent variable y.
r_yx2 (float): The correlation coefficient between x2 and y.
r_x1x2 (float): The correlation coefficient between the two measurements x1 and x2.
n_1 (int): The sample size for the first measurement.
n_2(int): The sample size for the second measurement.

Returns:
    
float: The difference in r-squared, 
       the variance,
       an adjusted version securing non-negative variance,
       and r_x1x2. The z-value and p-value.

"""

# Difference in r-squared

difference = r_yx1**2 - r_yx2**2

# 'Conservative criteria'

if r_x1x2 == None:

    r_x1x2 = np.minimum(r_yx1/r_yx2, r_yx2/r_yx1)

# Variance parts

var_r_yx1 = ((1 - r_yx1**2)**2) / n_1

var_r_yx2 = ((1 - r_yx2**2)**2) / n_2

# Covariance part

cov_x1x2 = ((1/2) * (2 * r_x1x2 - r_yx1 * r_yx2) * (1 - r_yx1**2 - r_yx2**2 - r_x1x2**2) + r_x1x2**3) / np.sqrt(n_1 * n_2)

# Variance-covariance matrix

phi = np.array([[var_r_yx1, cov_x1x2],
                [cov_x1x2, var_r_yx2]])

# Ensure the matrix is positive semi-definite

phi = (phi + phi.T) / 2  # Make the matrix symmetric

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(phi)

phi_positive_semi_definite = eigenvectors @ np.diag(np.maximum(eigenvalues, 0)) @ eigenvectors.T


# Coefficients for the linear combination

a = np.array([2 * r_yx1, -2 * r_yx2])

# Variance of the difference using the linear combination of variances and covariances

var_difference = a @ phi @ a.T

var_dif_adj = a @ phi_positive_semi_definite @ a.T

z_value = difference/np.sqrt(var_dif_adj)

p_value = 2 * (1 - stats.norm.cdf(abs(z_value)))

# Prepare the results

dif_results = {
    "Difference between two r-squared": difference,
    "Variance of the difference": var_difference,
    "Variance, adjusted": var_dif_adj,
    "Correlation": r_x1x2,
    "z-statistic": z_value,
    "p-value": p_value} 

return difference, var_difference, var_dif_adj, r_x1x2, z_value, p_value, dif_results
```

4. Example

difference, var_difference, var_dif_adj, r_x1x2, z_value, p_value, example = calculate_variance_of_difference(0.45, 0.433, 1415, 1415, r_x1x2 = None)

{'Difference between two r-squared': 0.015011, 'Variance of the difference': 3.345e-05, 'Variance, adjusted': 3.345e-05, 'Correlation': 0.96222222, 'z-statistic': 2.59534678, 'p-value': 0.00944955}

Comment: Could you explain why you are comparing $R^2$?  It sounds like your interest would like in comparing the measurements of $x,$ but comparing $R^2$ doesn't do that.

Comment: I want to compare which is 'best', measurement 1 (x1) or measurement 2 (x2), where x could be a vector of many variables, in explaining y. And if the difference is significant due to the measurement method.

Comment: Run both regressions and compare the results.  It doesn't sound like you're in a hypothesis testing situation (and therefore statistical significance is irrelevant), because you will settle on one answer: it will be the one that looks better for your data.

Comment: Yes. But should we not take into consideration the uncertainty of the difference before claiming that one measurement is 'better' than the alternative, more gererally?

Comment: It depends.  Suppose a hypothesis test told you the difference was not "significant."  What would you do then?

Comment: Conclude that H0 of no difference cannot be rejected in favor of HA

Comment: My question is whether that's at all useful to you.  Why would it matter?  If you are doing this testing to determine which measurement is best related to $y,$ wouldn't you use the one that comes out best in the testing whether or not you reject some null hypothesis?

Comment: Not if there for example are switching costs. Then there must be evidence of a 'significant' improvement, before changing measurement method?

Comment: Well, that's the kind of information I have been asking you to disclose!  Please provide this in your question.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because you really don't need to compare $R^2$ and there are mathematically equivalent methods that are much simpler than you have laid out here.  As a practical matter, though, you ought to be closely examining the full distributions of $(x,y)$ data to make sure your implicit assumptions (such as a near-linear relationship) even hold.